# menu item on CommandBar at a specified position

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, vsto, contextmenu, excel-2010

Is there a way to place a menu item/commandbarbutton on a CommandBar at a specified position? For example at position 0 (Top).

I am using straight forward code to Add() and I was disappointed to see AddAT() was not there. My menu appears and works fine. I would like to add it to a specified position.

```
button = (CommandBarButton)
    cellbar.Controls.Add(MsoControlType.msoControlButton, 
    Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
    cellbar.Controls.Count, true);
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 4th argument is "Before".  So change your code to:

```
button = (CommandBarButton)
    cellbar.Controls.Add(MsoControlType.msoControlButton, 
    Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
    1, true);
```